# Removing punctuation before tabulating data

Tags: r

I'm having issues with puling data from clipboard that happens to have lots of punctuation (quotes, commas, etc) in it. I'm attempting to pull in the [entirety of Jane Austen's Pride and Prejudice](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1342/pg1342.txt) as a plain text document via copying to clipboard into a variable in R for analysis.

If I do a

```
book <- read.table("clipboard", sep="\n")
```

I get an "EOF within quoted string" error. If I put the option to not have strings as factors:

```
book <- read.table("clipboard", sep="\n", stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I get the same error. This affects the table by putting multiple paragraphs together where quotations are present. If I open the book in a text editor and remove the double quotes and single quotes, then try either read.table option, the result is perfect.

Is there a way to remove punctuation prior to (or during?) the read.table phase? Would I dump the clipboard data into some kind of big vector then read.table off that vector?

Comment: Try `quote=""` in your `read.table()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to disable quoting

this works for me

```
book <-read.table("http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1342/pg1342.txt",
sep="\n",quote="",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: how can i split my code over multiple lines to make it more readable?

Answer (score 0):

The `read.table` function is intended to read in data in a rectangular structure and put it into a data frame.  I don't expect that the text of a book would fit that pattern in general.  I would suggest reading the data with the `scan` or `readLines` function in place of `read.table`.  Read the documentation for those functions on how to deal with quotes and separators.

If you still want to remove punctuation, then look at `?gsub`, if you also want to convert all the characters to upper or lower case see `?chartr`.

Comment: Adding to @Greg Snow, there is the [:punct:] character class for the pattern to match in gsub with "".  Second, there is the function tolower() to convert characters to lower case.